# In $\mathbb{R^2}$ once a subset intersection an open set leads to a point, is the relative topology of the subset the discrete one?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I read that as the subset (t,t) t $\in$ $\mathbb{R^2}$  intersection a particular open set is a point, the new relative topology is the discrete.

Comment: If $X$ is any topological space, $S\subseteq X$, and *every* one-point subset of $S$ is the intersection of $S$ with an open set of $X$, then the relative topology on $S$ is the discrete topology, because every subset of $S$ is a union of open sets (namely the singletons).

Comment: $(t,t)$ is a point, not a subset. Did you mean $\{(t,t)\}$ ?

Comment: Also, is $t$ a real number, or an element of $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: There is only one topology on a 1-point set. No other topology is possible. That topology is both discrete and indiscrete (or *trivial*. , if you prefer), since there is only one point in the set. So yes, the relative topology that $\{(t,t)\}$ inherits from $\Bbb R$ is discrete. However, this fact is also completely useless.

Comment: Yes, I meant {(t,t): t $\in$ R}